# Execute jQuery function each time scroll on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a recurrent animation that i need to insert inside a web page. 
I use an animation to show a number progression on the web page. I need just a call to this animation function each time I go hover the section but the code below behave in a strange manner. The animation is executed correctly for the first time but after the animation end it performs a sort of rollback, executing the animation in the opposite way returning to value 1. 
The code I use is reported below:

```js
$("#numberFarm").hover(function() {
  $('.countIncrement .count').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function(now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="numberFarm">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>i nostri numeri</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="box_icon"><img src="/assets/images/transport_icon.png" /></div>
        <div class="divCountIncrement">
          <h4 class="countIncrement"><span class="count">38</span> <br/><span class="numberDesc">veicoli</h4></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-4"> <div class="box_icon"><img src="/assets/images/persons_icon.png" /></div> <div class="divCountIncrement"><h4 class="countIncrement"><span class="count">43</span> <br/><span class="numberDesc">staff</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="box_icon"><img src="/assets/images/kilo_icon.png" /></div>
        <div class="divCountIncrement">
          <h4 class="countIncrement"><span class="count">2</span> <br/><span class="numberDesc">milioni di km percorsi</span></h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Do you have any explanation for this strange behavior? 
How can I solve this problem to prevent the return to the original condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `$("#numberFarm").hover(function () {` needs a another `function()`

#### Example:

```
$( the-element ).hover(
  function() {
    //this is the `mouseenter`
  }, function() {
     //this is the `mouseleave`
  }
);
```

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element.
>
> Calling `$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand
>   for:
>
> ```
> $( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
> ```

Read the [documentation of .hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)